# django_filters (Associative table, reverse foreign key)

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

I am using django_filters to create filters. 
My models in models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):

  Name = models.CharField("Name", max_length = 50)

class School(models.Model):

  Name = models.CharField("School Name", db_column='Name', max_length=50)

class Person_School(models.Model):

  PersonID = models.ForeignKey(Person, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PersonID')
  SchoolID = models.ForeignKey(School, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SchoolID')
```

The 'Person_School' is an associative table that links 'Person' and 'School'. I want to create a drop down list in front end that contains university names, people's names can be filtered by university names. I only know basic function of django_filters, but have no idea when there is an associative table. How should I code in filters.py using django_filters?  Thanks

Comment: Try adding an m2m field using `Person_School` as a [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table. You should then be able to create a regular `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`.

Comment: Could you explain more for me? I tried to add 'Schools = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='PersonToSchool')' in School Class, and then in filters.py, should I filter in Person model or School model? I always get [invalid name] for the filter in front page.

Comment: The M2M definition seems incorrect. A school has persons or students, so the M2M field on the School model should probably be `Students = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='PersonToSchool')` instead of `Schools = ...`. You can filter either model, although if you filter by the Person model, you're doing so from the *reverse* side of the M2M relationship. I'd recommend exploring [M2M fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many) and understanding how to filter through both sides of the relationship before continuing with django-filter integration.